# The type or namespace name 'System' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Win32'

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, resharper

I have a .Net5.0-windows project, where I have the following function:

```
public static void EnableDisplayTimeout()
{
     PInvoke.SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
}
```

This requires using Windows.Win32.System.Power, which the intellisense recognizes, offers me the proper import and then everything seems to be in order. When I try to build the project, it fail with the error     `Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'System' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Win32' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (2, 21)`.

I'm not sure I understand the problem. I'm new to .NET, so I'm not sure I understand the inner workings of VS. I'm using VS 2019, CsWin32 NuGet with ReSharper 2021.1.3. I've already tried to disable ReSharper, but the problem is still present. Am I missing some configuration steps?

Comment: Can you provide what usings are you using for this class? Issue seems to be in there somewhere

Comment: Try cleaning out your bin and obj folders and rebuilding? Make sure you've restored all nuget packages, too.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak I'm only using System.Windows, Windows.Win32 and Windows.Win32.System.Power

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I've tried these just now, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an sdk bug. I upgraded to .net sdk 6, and the problem went away.

Found the solution based on these:
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32/issues/7
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3404

Answer (score 0):

You sure about `Windows.Win32` namespace? Maybe [Microsoft.Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) should be? Or [Windows.System.Power](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power?view=winrt-22000)? Or nothing of that, because `SetThreadExecutionState` doesn't exists there and taken from **kernel32.dll** by `DllImport`:

`PInvoke.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class PInvoke
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
        {
            ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);
    }
}
```

And usage:

`Program.cs`:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var executionState = PInvoke.SetThreadExecutionState(PInvoke.EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
            Console.WriteLine(executionState);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering the nature of the error, I'm not sure about anything. If I don't use Windows.Win32, PInvoke is marked with "Cannot resolve symbol", and it's the intellisense that suggests to import Windows.Win32.